# SQL - Query records within an undefined interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, northwind

I need to get the following data from `Orders` table in `Northwind` database using SQL (SQL Server to be exact):

- Find all customers (`CustomerID`) who placed at least 3 orders within
  the interval of 6 months (`OrderDate`).

So for the following data the query should return `1`

```
==========================
| CustomerID | OrderDate |
==========================
|      1     | 2000-1-1  |
--------------------------
|      1     | 2000-1-5  |
--------------------------
|      1     | 2000-4-30 |
--------------------------
|      2     | 2000-1-1  |
--------------------------
|      2     | 2000-5-30 |
--------------------------
```

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: Try this:
SELECT N1.CustomerID, COUNT(N2.OrderDate)  FROM Northwind N1
INNER JOIN Northwind N2
ON N1.CustomerID=N2.CustomerID
AND N1.OrderDate<=Dateadd(MONTH, 6, N2.OrderDate)
GROUP BY N1.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(N2.OrderDate)>=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT N1.CustomerID, COUNT(N2.OrderDate)  FROM Northwind N1
INNER JOIN Northwind N2
ON N1.CustomerID=N2.CustomerID
AND N1.OrderDate<=Dateadd(MONTH, 6, N2.OrderDate)
GROUP BY N1.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(N2.OrderDate)>=3
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT OrderDate, CustomerID FROM orders GROUP BY OrderDate HAVING   COUNT(CustomerID) >= 3 ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC
```

Comment: You answer is not correct, the objectif is to list  all customers (CustomerID) who placed at least 3 orders within the interval of 6 months (OrderDate).